# Missing amdgpu firmware file named vega20_ta.bin | Kubuntu 19.04

Tags: kernel, initramfs, firmware, amdgpu, cryptsetup

Recently, after each upgrade I get these lines at the end of the process:

```
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.131ubuntu19) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-17-generic
cryptsetup: ERROR: Couldn't resolve device 048c7724-eed7-4e49-979f-f77f3d4dbfdb
cryptsetup: WARNING: The initramfs image may not contain cryptsetup binaries 
    nor crypto modules. If that's on purpose, you may want to uninstall the 
    'cryptsetup-initramfs' package in order to disable the cryptsetup initramfs 
    integration and avoid this warning.
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/vega20_ta.bin for module amdgpu
```

I have searched for the file in [kernel repository](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/amdgpu) but couldn't find the missing file `vega20_ta.bin`.

#### System specs:

- Kubuntu 19.04
- Kernel 5.0.0-17-generic

Answer (score 0):

The vega20_ta.bin is not release yet as it is optional and the board didn't seem to use it and it just a warning as you can see by W: so you can safely ignore the message.